# Include the same config file by two PHP scripts

Tags: php

I have this situation where scriptA needs to read the config variable from file "config.php" before calling the function in scriptB which is using the same config, but I have the following error in scriptB

"Notice: Undefined variable: cfg_variable", so basically what ScriptA has to do ?

```
<?php
// config.php
$cfg_variable = 'DEMO';
?>
```

////

```
<?php 
// scriptA.php
require 'scriptB.php';
include 'config.php';

echo $cfg_variable;
scriptB_function();

?>
```

////

```
<?php

// scriptB.php 
function scriptB_function()
{ 
   require_once "config.php";
   echo $cfg_variable; // <= Error : "Notice: Undefined variable"
}

?>
```

Comment: Is $cfg_variable defined in the right way in the config file?

Comment: Well, `require_once` won't include the file when it's already been included previously.

Comment: You forgot to precede the variable name with a dollar sign in ScriptA. Closing as a typo.

Comment: Isn't `$cfg_variable` a global variable now? Why require again?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `$cfg_variable` inside the function from the other file, you need to pass it while calling the function:

```
<?php 
// scriptA.php
require 'scriptB.php';
include 'config.php';
$check = scriptB_function($cfg_variable);

?>
```

And in the scriptB file:

```
<?php
// scriptB.php 
function scriptB_function($cfg_variable){ 
   //require_once "config.php";
   //You don't really need to require the config again
   echo $cfg_variable;
}

?>
```

And lastly, define the variables in PHP using the `$` sign.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo and the problem is that scriptB could be used by others ?

Comment: What do you mean `used by others` ?

Comment: Basically those configs(serverconfig, etc..) are for an email function and I want script A to read those configs without disrupting the way function B works, is there any other solution ?

Comment: Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742507/best-practice-to-hide-secure-the-php-engine-config-file)

Comment: I found the solution which is basically to remove the require_once and replace it with require.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I had to remove require_once from function B and replace it with require

require_once "config.php" to require "config.php";